# beamer + polyglossia: manual hyphenation

Tags: beamer, luatex, hyphenation, polyglossia

I have the following beamer frame:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands]{italian}
\disablehyphenation % to follow beamer documentation

\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}

\usetheme[right]{PaloAlto}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Bias di genere
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Rimuovere appros-\linebreak{}simativamente la direzione corri\-spondente al genere.
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Bias di genere
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Rimuovere approssimativamente la direzione corrispondente al genere.
                \end{itemize}
                \item Nomi propri
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item New York Times
                    \item non si conosce l'offset tra il termini in output e quello in input
                    \item modello addestrato con frasi di \(n\)-grammi
                \end{itemize}
                \item Parole polisemiche
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item<presentation:.-> mouse: roditore, componente HW o altro?
                    \item Word vector contestuali (BERT)
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I compiled it with

```bash
latexmk -lualatex ./foo.tex
```

using TeXLive2023 updated.

Unfortunately after compilation I got

```
Overfull \vbox (2.0399pt too high) detected at line 42
```

Even if beamer [documentation says](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#page=34):

> Do not hyphenate words. If absolutely necessary, hyphenate words “by hand,” using the command \-.

I would want to hyphen some words to remove that annoying `Overfull`. So I tried to use `\-` without successful. Then I used `-\linebreath{}` but I don't like this solution.

Can someone know a better (more appropriate) solution?

Comment: overfull vbox has nothing to do with hyphenation, it means that you have to much vertical material. Your text is overwriting the bottom.

Comment: You can avoid the problem by making the left column a bit smaller and the right column wider.

Comment: Thank @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ! I didn't think to your solution. To be honest I didn't want to reduce column size because I thought that my audience could notice it. But I reduced the columns just enough and I think it is very difficult to see the difference at least that you don't read the code.

Comment: @miticollo As beamer uses ragged right text, small differences in column width are normally not very noticeable - an you really only need to safe one line, so not a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@UlrikeFischer already said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701009/beamer-polyglossia-manual-hyphenation#comment1743008_701009) in the comments, the warning indicates an overfull vertical box. In your case this means that the content of your slide is too tall to fit on the frame without overlapping the footline.

You can avoid this problem by making your right hand column a tiny bit wider. This will safe you one or two lines, which is enough to avoid the overfull box. As beamer uses ragged right text, this mismatch in column widths won't be very noticeable:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands]{italian}
\disablehyphenation % to follow beamer documentation

\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usetheme[right]{PaloAlto}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Bias di genere
                \begin{itemize}
                    \RaggedRight
                    \item Rimuovere appros-\linebreak{}simativamente la direzione corri\-spondente al genere.
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.53\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Bias di genere
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Rimuovere approssimativamente la direzione corrispondente al genere.
                \end{itemize}
                \item Nomi propri
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item New York Times
                    \item non si conosce l'offset tra il termini in output e quello in input
                    \item modello addestrato con frasi di \(n\)-grammi
                \end{itemize}
                \item Parole polisemiche
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item<presentation:.-> mouse: roditore, componente HW o altro?
                    \item Word vector contestuali (BERT)
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late to accept this answer. Can you show me how to hyphen a word on this frame? I ask to you this to address those issues that you can’t solve them changing column size. 
I usually don’t manually hyphen words because I use polyglossia. But when I tried to use `\-` on this frame it didn’t work unless I removed the `\usepackage{polyglossia}` (IIRC).

Comment: @miticollo See my edit https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/701167/revisions